# Corda Token SDK - Eliminating encumbered tokens from selection

Tags: corda

Is there a way to encumber tokens in Corda and eliminate encumbered tokens when selecting tokens for transfer?

I want to transfer tokens to a different party (Party B) and make them encumbered on certain conditions. While in Party B's ledger I do not want those tokens encumbered tokens to be selected when Party B is looking to transfer its tokens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way you could do this is with contract verification conditions. It might be easier to leave the states as encumbered and use contract verification to ensure that they can't be used. At the time you run the flow on B might be the right time to ensure that a state is NOT encumbered before trying to use it. Even easier might be just using the contract verification for encumbrance and having the caller of B responsible for finding an unencumbered state to use.

Hopefully that helps.

There's some more details on this in the documentation: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/tutorial-contract.html#defining-encumbrances

Be aware also there are some encumbered state limitations: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/reissuing-states.html#reissuance-of-encumbered-states-is-not-supported